# Solve works with symbols, not with numbers

Tags: equation-solving

I don't understand why, in the code below, Solve works with symbols, but substituting numerical values (rational) for the symbolic parameters makes it unsolvable:

```
Clear[mo, RT, n]

dG = mo + 2 RT Log[n/(1 + n)] - RT Log[-1 + 2/(1 + n)]
Solve[dG == 0, n]

vals = {mo -> 79900, RT -> 6197399567/2500000};
dGvals = dG /. vals
Solve[dGvals == 0, n]
```

Mathematica 11.2.0.0 on Mac OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the precedence of simplifications undertaken by `Solve` for symbolic vs. numeric values.  It turns out that for the latter case `Solve` tries another route of solution and gets trapped into a very inefficient procedure and eventually gives up.

Let us simplify your problem. In fact, there is a single relevant parameter `mo/RT`

```
xN=79900/(6197399567/2500000)//N
(*   32.2313 *)
```

The respective equation is

```
eq=x+2Log[n/(1+n)]-Log[-1+2/(1+n)]
```

Let us approximate `xN` in 3 different ways and see what happens.

- Integer (`32`)

---

```
val=Rationalize[xN,1]
Solve[eq==0/.x->val,n]
Out[1]= 32
Out[2]= {{n->1/Sqrt[1+E^32]}}
```

Fine, this work as expected.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{32}}}$$

- Simplest rational number (`129/4`)

---

```
val=Rationalize[xN,0.1]
Solve[eq==0/.x->val,n]
Out[3]= 129/4
Out[4]= {{n->Sqrt[(-1+E^(129/4)-E^(129/2)+E^(387/4))/(-1+E^129)]}}
```

Here, the solution is still possible, but it has a completely different (**and equivalent form**)
$$\sqrt{\frac{-1+e^{129/4}-e^{129/2}+e^{387/4}}{-1+e^{129}}}$$

- Finally (`290/9`)

---

```
val=Rationalize[xN,0.01]
Solve[eq==0/.x->val,n]
Out[5]= 290/9
Out[6]= {{n->1/Sqrt[(1+E^290)/(1-E^(290/9)+E^(580/9)-E^(290/3)+E^(1160/9)-E^(1450/9)+E^(580/3)-E^(2030/9)+E^(2320/9))]}}
```

or in human-readable form
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1+e^{290}}{1-e^{290/9}+e^{580/9}-e^{290/3}+e^{1160/9}-e^{1450/9}+e^{580/3}-e^{2030/9}+e^{2320/9}}}}$$

If we continue with more and more accurate `val` the expression get more and more complicated until it reaches the point that MA cannot handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try: Reduce[dGvals == 0, n, Reals]

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dG = mo + 2 RT Log[n/(1 + n)] - RT Log[-1 + 2/(1 + n)];

sol1 = Solve[dG == 0, n]

(* {{n -> -(1/Sqrt[1 + E^(mo/RT)])}, {n -> 1/Sqrt[1 + E^(mo/RT)]}} *)
```

Restricting the domain to `Reals` gives a single solution that is positive. `Solve[expr, vars, Reals]` restricts all variables, parameters, constants, and function values to belong to the domain `Reals`.

```
sol2 = Solve[dG == 0, n, Reals] // Simplify

(* {{n -> Sqrt[1/(1 + E^(mo/RT))]}} *)

vals = {mo -> 79900, RT -> 6197399567/2500000};

dGvals = dG /. vals;
```

To use `Solve` with  `dGvals`, restrict the domain to `Reals`. Again, this eliminates one of the roots.

```
sol3 = Solve[dGvals == 0, n, Reals]

(* {{n -> 1/Sqrt[1 + E^(199750000000/6197399567)]}} *)
```

Alternatively, restrict `n` to being positive

```
sol4 = Solve[dGvals == 0 && n > 0, n]

(* {{n -> 1/Sqrt[1 + E^(199750000000/6197399567)]}} *)
```

**EDIT:** More specifically, for positive values of `mo` and `RT`

```
Simplify[
 FunctionDomain[
  {mo + 2 RT Log[n/(1 + n)] - RT Log[-1 + 2/(1 + n)],
   mo > 0, RT > 0}, n], {mo > 0, RT > 0}]

(* 0 < n < 1 *)

({sol1[[2]]} /. vals) == (sol2 /. vals) == sol3 == sol4

(* True *)
```

Comment: This works, thank you, but it seems like a "trick". I'd feel better if I understood why the trick works, understood why the use of numbers stops Solve for no apparent reason that I can see.

Comment: @PaulR. My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that adding `MaxExtraConditions->All` to the symbolic case also stops `Solve` from giving solutions - it looks like it's doing some questionable transformations that are not valid in all cases, including the case of the values given by `vals` (notice also that `dG/.Solve[dG==0,n]/.vals//N` shows that one of the solutions is not valid). By restricting the domain to `Reals` you're probably giving `Solve` enough hints to make it be sure about what transformations are allowed

Comment: @LukasLang See my solution suggesting what could be a possible reason.

Comment: @yarchik I've seen it, thanks! Nice insight into the process of `Solve`

Comment: @yarchik - Excellent! Thank you.